# Linq To Entities Get 2nd Last entry In List

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following code which returns a list of Objects.

```
var listOfLogins = _logService.GetLogEventsByItemID(137).ToList();
```

I would like to get the 2nd last object in this list.

Does anyone know how to do this using Linq to Entities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var secondlast = _logService.GetLogEventsByItemID(137)
    .Reverse()
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update**
@Dherik makes a good point in his comment that `.Reverse` is not actually supported in LINQ to Entities and will result in the query being evaluated at the point of calling reverse, rather than at the point of calling `.FirstOrDefault`. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx) for all (not) supported methods.

The alternative (LINQ to Entities friendly) solution requires that you have a suitable field to order by (which must be the case anyway otherwise "second last" has no relevance):

```
var secondlast = _logService.GetLogEventsByItemID(137)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.EventDate /* could be any db field */)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Does LINQ to Entities recognize the method "Reverse()"?

Comment: @Dherik. Good point, though I wish you spotted this two years ago! I've updated my answer to provide a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] items = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int item = items.Skip(items.Count() - 2).Take(1).Single();
    //will return 9
```

like this?

Comment: Carlos Brazao Yeah, thats another way. Thanks.

Comment: @Luiz. This would work but would make two calls to the database. One to do the count, the other to return the result.